# File transfer using SIP server

Tags: android, file, wifi, sip, asterisk

I am planning to build an application to transfer a file from one android phone to other using SIP server. Is it possible to implement this by using Android's native SIP APIs?
Thank you!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [File transfer using SIP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240934/file-transfer-using-sip)

Comment: Most likely not. Use MSRP or cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your file into multiple sip messages with type MESSAGE and send it via android sip API. but anyway that is not nice way.

For messaging better use jabber.